# Audio translation help!

Tags: translation, meaning, anime

Hullo!

I'm watching a new anime with some friends for the first time and we found some post episode web commentary online and we're trying to understand a joke but we can't quite get what it's about.

Here is the full excerpt if there is some important context https://uploadir.com/u/yo3zj2if

And here is the part we are trying to get https://uploadir.com/u/hz1gecmx

I tried to transcribe it but it's probably not right ehheh:

> 今までさんざんせわになっては危機をあっさりガラ携とかガラクタみたい呼ぶ人間にだけはなりたくないということだ。"

The way I understand it is "I really don't wish to become one of the people who are quick to dismiss flip-phones as a piece of junk". And I think the joke is that flip-phone has the same ring to it as junk (garake, gara-keitai). But I'm not certain that's what he means because maybe I hear some of the words wrong.

edit: maybe instead of せわに it's せえわにん. and instead of 危機 it's 機器.
Then maybe it's like "even thorough assistants are quick to call devices like that "garake"(flip phone), as if invoking the sound of junk by these people, but I don't wish to call it that"?

Hmm, that still doesn't sound like much of a joke...

Comment: Can you make an attempt to translate your sentence and explain which part/s you are stuck on and why? If you don't, your question will probably be closed as a 'translation request'.

Comment: Yeah the way I understand it is "I really don't wish to become one of the people who are quick to dismiss flip-phones as a piece of junk"

And I think the joke is that flip-phone has the same ring to it as junk (garake, gara-keitai).

But I'm not certain that's what he means because maybe I hear some of the words wrong.

Comment: The part I'm stuck on is that I'm not sure if I hear it correctly.

Comment: I edited your comment in. I'm not good enough to answer your question but I’m sure you have a typo with さんざん散々. I heard さんざんせわ

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't notice that, that's a typo on my part.

Answer (score 3):

> 今までさんざん**世話になってた機器**をあっさり「ガラケー」とかガラクタみたい**に**呼ぶ人間にだけはなりたくないということだ。
>
> The last thing I want to do is to become a person who lightly calls the device I've always relied on "garake" (like "garakuta" / as if it were junk).

世話になってた is short for 世話になっていた, and [世話になる](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%96%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B) is a common set phrase. ("relied on" is my free translation.)

This きき is not 危機 but 機器 ("device").

ガラケー was [named after ガラパゴス ("*Gala*pagos") ケータイ](http://www.japansubculture.com/the-cell-phone-from-galapagos-japans-gara-kei-%E3%82%AC%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%80%80/), but it happens to sound like ガラクタ ("junk"), which is the "joke" here. You've got this part right.